# Using car weight in parking ramps to create energy

Tags: energy, weight

What if... large parking ramps had an optional car elevator on the upper floors that allowed drivers the option of using that to descend to the ground level. As your car goes down the empty counter lift would go up. If several hundred cars did this per day couldn't that weight energy be harvested? And the incentive for drivers to use it is that your car would get to the ground level faster. Has this been explored or is there something functionally flawed with this idea?

Comment: How can you run a turbine or even a dynamo?

Comment: This is a suggestion for improving energy use in the community. It is not a question about physics.

Comment: Thanks Sammy... I got here by following another energy-related thread and then clicking "ask a question." I wasn't aware I was posting it in the wrong community.

Answer (score 1):

The average car weighs about 1 tonne. Let's suppose the average height of a single floor in a parking lot is about 4 metres. Let's also suppose that you could extract the gravitational potential energy from a car with 100% efficiency. The total energy you could extract per car per floor is roughly 40 kJ. That's enough energy to run a single 100 W lightbulb for about 7 minutes.

So if you had a car use the elevator once every 7 minutes, and suppose there are 5 floors, that gives you enough energy to keep 5 lightbulbs continuously running.

Now also offset that against the cost (and energy!) of constructing such a device...

Comment: Thanks for putting some numbers around this. If the lift was built into the original construction it of the parking ramp it might not impact the overall cost that much. At a minimum it might power the lights to the parking ramp itself!